# Clickhouse Distributed Query take huge amount of network usage when using group by

Tags: distributed, clickhouse

**Describe the unexpected behaviour**

the following SQL execution will bump network usage to 500Mb/s, and take approximately 2 second on network transmission:

```sql
SELECT
    user_id,
    count() AS c
FROM semanticdb_chatbi.I11066 AS test
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY c DESC
LIMIT 10
```

**How to reproduce**

- Which ClickHouse server version to use

22.3.20.29

- `CREATE TABLE` statements for all tables involved

4 nodes with 4 shards, 1 replica

1. local table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE semanticdb_chatbi.I11066_local ON CLUSTER '{cluster}'
(
    `statis_date` DateTime COMMENT 'date',
    `user_id` String COMMENT 'ID',
    `fee` Nullable(Float64) COMMENT '收入'
)
ENGINE = ReplicatedMergeTree('/clickhouse/{installation}/{cluster}/tables/{shard}/semanticdb_chatbi/I11066_local', '{replica}')
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(statis_date)
ORDER BY statis_date
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

2, distributed table

```sql
 CREATE TABLE semanticdb_chatbi.I11066
(
    `statis_date` DateTime COMMENT 'date',
    `user_id` String COMMENT 'ID',
    `fee` Nullable(Float64) COMMENT '收入'
)
ENGINE = Distributed('{cluster}', 'semanticdb_chatbi', 'I11066_local', cityHash64(user_id))
```

- number of rows on cluster

600Million

**query log in json**

```json
{
        "meta":
        [
                {
                        "name": "type",
                        "type": "Enum8('QueryStart' = 1, 'QueryFinish' = 2, 'ExceptionBeforeStart' = 3, 'ExceptionWhileProcessing' = 4)"
                },
                {
                        "name": "event_date",
                        "type": "Date"
                },
                {
                        "name": "event_time",
                        "type": "DateTime"
                },
                {
                        "name": "event_time_microseconds",
                        "type": "DateTime64(6)"
                },
                {
                        "name": "query_start_time",
                        "type": "DateTime"
                },
                {
                        "name": "query_start_time_microseconds",
                        "type": "DateTime64(6)"
                },
                {
                        "name": "query_duration_ms",
                        "type": "UInt64"
                },
                {
                        "name": "read_rows",
                        "type": "UInt64"
                },
                {
                        "name": "read_bytes",
                        "type": "UInt64"
                },
                {
                        "name": "written_rows",
                        "type": "UInt64"
                },
                {
                        "name": "written_bytes",
                        "type": "UInt64"
                },
                {
                        "name": "result_rows",
                        "type": "UInt64"
                },
                {
                        "name": "result_bytes",
                        "type": "UInt64"
                },
                {
                        "name": "memory_usage",
                        "type": "UInt64"
                },
                {
                        "name": "current_database",
                        "type": "String"
                },
                {
                        "name": "query",
                        "type": "String"
                },
                {
                        "name": "formatted_query",
                        "type": "String"
                },
                {
                        "name": "normalized_query_hash",
                        "type": "UInt64"
                },
                {
                        "name": "query_kind",
                        "type": "LowCardinality(String)"
                },
                {
                        "name": "databases",
                        "type": "Array(LowCardinality(String))"
                },
                {
                        "name": "tables",
                        "type": "Array(LowCardinality(String))"
                },
                {
                        "name": "columns",
                        "type": "Array(LowCardinality(String))"
                },
                {
                        "name": "projections",
                        "type": "Array(LowCardinality(String))"
                },
                {
                        "name": "views",
                        "type": "Array(LowCardinality(String))"
                },
                {
                        "name": "exception_code",
                        "type": "Int32"
                },
                {
                        "name": "exception",
                        "type": "String"
                },
                {
                        "name": "stack_trace",
                        "type": "String"
                },
                {
                        "name": "is_initial_query",
                        "type": "UInt8"
                },
                {
                        "name": "user",
                        "type": "String"
                },
                {
                        "name": "query_id",
                        "type": "String"
                },
                {
                        "name": "address",
                        "type": "IPv6"
                },
                {
                        "name": "port",
                        "type": "UInt16"
                },
                {
                        "name": "initial_user",
                        "type": "String"
                },
                {
                        "name": "initial_query_id",
                        "type": "String"
                },
                {
                        "name": "initial_address",
                        "type": "IPv6"
                },
                {
                        "name": "initial_port",
                        "type": "UInt16"
                },
                {
                        "name": "initial_query_start_time",
                        "type": "DateTime"
                },
                {
                        "name": "initial_query_start_time_microseconds",
                        "type": "DateTime64(6)"
                },
                {
                        "name": "interface",
                        "type": "UInt8"
                },
                {
                        "name": "os_user",
                        "type": "String"
                },
                {
                        "name": "client_hostname",
                        "type": "String"
                },
                {
                        "name": "client_name",
                        "type": "String"
                },
                {
                        "name": "client_revision",
                        "type": "UInt32"
                },
                {
                        "name": "client_version_major",
                        "type": "UInt32"
                },
                {
                        "name": "client_version_minor",
                        "type": "UInt32"
                },
                {
                        "name": "client_version_patch",
                        "type": "UInt32"
                },
                {
                        "name": "http_method",
                        "type": "UInt8"
                },
                {
                        "name": "http_user_agent",
                        "type": "String"
                },
                {
                        "name": "http_referer",
                        "type": "String"
                },
                {
                        "name": "forwarded_for",
                        "type": "String"
                },
                {
                        "name": "quota_key",
                        "type": "String"
                },
                {
                        "name": "distributed_depth",
                        "type": "UInt64"
                },
                {
                        "name": "revision",
                        "type": "UInt32"
                },
                {
                        "name": "log_comment",
                        "type": "String"
                },
                {
                        "name": "thread_ids",
                        "type": "Array(UInt64)"
                },
                {
                        "name": "ProfileEvents",
                        "type": "Map(String, UInt64)"
                },
                {
                        "name": "Settings",
                        "type": "Map(String, String)"
                },
                {
                        "name": "used_aggregate_functions",
                        "type": "Array(String)"
                },
                {
                        "name": "used_aggregate_function_combinators",
                        "type": "Array(String)"
                },
                {
                        "name": "used_database_engines",
                        "type": "Array(String)"
                },
                {
                        "name": "used_data_type_families",
                        "type": "Array(String)"
                },
                {
                        "name": "used_dictionaries",
                        "type": "Array(String)"
                },
                {
                        "name": "used_formats",
                        "type": "Array(String)"
                },
                {
                        "name": "used_functions",
                        "type": "Array(String)"
                },
                {
                        "name": "used_storages",
                        "type": "Array(String)"
                },
                {
                        "name": "used_table_functions",
                        "type": "Array(String)"
                }
        ],

        "data":
        [
                {
                        "type": "QueryFinish",
                        "event_date": "2024-03-09",
                        "event_time": "2024-03-09 15:39:15",
                        "event_time_microseconds": "2024-03-09 15:39:15.535252",
                        "query_start_time": "2024-03-09 15:39:11",
                        "query_start_time_microseconds": "2024-03-09 15:39:11.698048",
                        "query_duration_ms": "3836",
                        "read_rows": "642330674",
                        "read_bytes": "14131246634",
                        "written_rows": "0",
                        "written_bytes": "0",
                        "result_rows": "10",
                        "result_bytes": "512",
                        "memory_usage": "89259629",
                        "current_database": "semanticdb_chatbi",
                        "query": "SELECT\n    user_id,\n    count() AS c\nFROM semanticdb_chatbi.I11066 AS test\nGROUP BY user_id\nORDER BY c DESC\nLIMIT 10",
                        "formatted_query": "",
                        "normalized_query_hash": "10840967859924656691",
                        "query_kind": "Select",
                        "databases": ["semanticdb_chatbi"],
                        "tables": ["semanticdb_chatbi.I11066"],
                        "columns": ["semanticdb_chatbi.I11066.user_id"],
                        "projections": [],
                        "views": [],
                        "exception_code": 0,
                        "exception": "",
                        "stack_trace": "",
                        "is_initial_query": 1,
                        "user": "default",
                        "query_id": "f238bb70-a22b-4294-aec4-138a4705e025",
                        "address": "::ffff:127.0.0.1",
                        "port": 45112,
                        "initial_user": "default",
                        "initial_query_id": "f238bb70-a22b-4294-aec4-138a4705e025",
                        "initial_address": "::ffff:127.0.0.1",
                        "initial_port": 45112,
                        "initial_query_start_time": "2024-03-09 15:39:11",
                        "initial_query_start_time_microseconds": "2024-03-09 15:39:11.698048",
                        "interface": 1,
                        "os_user": "",
                        "client_hostname": "chi-clickhouse-local-storage-local-storage-2-0-0.chi-clickhouse-local-storage-local-storage-2-0.chatbi.svc.cluster.local",
                        "client_name": "ClickHouse ",
                        "client_revision": 54455,
                        "client_version_major": 22,
                        "client_version_minor": 3,
                        "client_version_patch": 20,
                        "http_method": 0,
                        "http_user_agent": "",
                        "http_referer": "",
                        "forwarded_for": "",
                        "quota_key": "",
                        "distributed_depth": "0",
                        "revision": 54460,
                        "log_comment": "",
                        "thread_ids": ["16904","16635","15904","13174","16560","16255","16430","16472","16514","16518","15691","16188","12493","9694","15323","16451","16013","9136","12298","16125","16384","16730","13895","16574","16571","16067","15088","14924","16176","14574","14369","15872","9126","15618"],
                        "ProfileEvents": {"Query":"1","SelectQuery":"1","ReadCompressedBytes":"43069298","CompressedReadBufferBlocks":"774","CompressedReadBufferBytes":"59988459","IOBufferAllocs":"6","IOBufferAllocBytes":"3389588","ArenaAllocChunks":"5888","ArenaAllocBytes":"196083712","NetworkReceiveElapsedMicroseconds":"72311","NetworkSendElapsedMicroseconds":"5572","NetworkReceiveBytes":"68305516","NetworkSendBytes":"5749097","SelectedRows":"642330674","SelectedBytes":"14131246634","ContextLock":"3712","RWLockAcquiredReadLocks":"2","RealTimeMicroseconds":"130211245","UserTimeMicroseconds":"1796646","SystemTimeMicroseconds":"183466","SoftPageFaults":"1153","OSCPUWaitMicroseconds":"746687","OSCPUVirtualTimeMicroseconds":"1979942","OSWriteBytes":"61440","OSReadChars":"56158","OSWriteChars":"136752","QueryProfilerRuns":"133"},
                        "Settings": {"connect_timeout_with_failover_ms":"1000","load_balancing":"nearest_hostname","distributed_aggregation_memory_efficient":"1","do_not_merge_across_partitions_select_final":"1","os_thread_priority":"2","log_queries":"1","max_memory_usage":"10000000000","prefer_localhost_replica":"0","parallel_view_processing":"1"},
                        "used_aggregate_functions": ["count"],
                        "used_aggregate_function_combinators": [],
                        "used_database_engines": [],
                        "used_data_type_families": ["Int64","Enum8","UInt64","DateTime","AggregateFunction","String"],
                        "used_dictionaries": [],
                        "used_formats": [],
                        "used_functions": [],
                        "used_storages": [],
                        "used_table_functions": []
                }

        ],

        "rows": 1,

        "rows_before_limit_at_least": 1,

        "statistics":
        {
                "elapsed": 0.044576104,
                "rows_read": 47068,
                "bytes_read": 13481440
        }
}
```

**Expected behaviour**

I think CK should first calculate the top 10 c on each node locally and then merge the 4 * 10 results globally. so i think there is only 40 rows need to be sent across the cluster.

**More Infomation**

i thought maybe CK will not limit rows locally. so i've tried group by user gender without limit clause, it result only 2 rows on each node after group by. the network usage dropped, but still at a very high level: 20Mb/s

**What I need**

1. i'd like to know why the statement take so many network transmission
2. and how to optimize the query

thanks

Comment: You should understand, that summing top 10 groups on each node may not produce the same result as your initial query. All groups must be computed on each node to get correct result. You can get top 10 groups on each node and merge the result with the `cluster` function invocation. Let us know if you really want to get such a result.

Comment: my sharding_key is the same as group by key, so in this case maybe summing top 10 groups on each node will surely produce the same result as my initial query. am i right?

Comment: `You can get top 10 groups on each node and merge the result with the cluster function invocation.`  how to do it?

Comment: Yes, it's really possible to get top 10 groups from each node and merge the result just because of grouping by the column used in the distribution key expression. All rows for each user should be on the same node. If you insert data with distributed table only of course.

Comment: thank u very much!  as long as the operator used in select list is additive, the merged result will be always correct, i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging top 10 groups from each node.
Note that it's logically the same as getting top 10 groups from the whole table because of group by the same column used in the distribution key expression.

```
select
  user_id
, sum(c) as cnt
from cluster
(
 '{cluster}'
, view
(
SELECT
    user_id,
    count() AS c
FROM semanticdb_chatbi.I11066_local
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY c DESC
LIMIT 10
)
)
group by user_id
order by cnt desc
limit 10
```

Comment: @kilik52 BTW, outer `group by` is not necessary. Just `ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 10`is sufficient.

Comment: thank u. if user_id is not sharding key, adding outer group by will still get the right result. right?

Comment: If user_id is not a sharding key then such an approach can't get correct result at all w/ or w/o `group by`.